# How to reduce size of jpeg image in basic4android

Tags: basic4android

Hello at this time camera capturing image size is more than 1 mb. I want to reduce it to 20kb. Please help me.

```
Sub Camera1_PictureTaken (Data() As Byte)
    camera1.StartPreview
    DateTime.DateFormat ="HH.mm.ss.SS_dd-MM-yy_"
    forDate=DateTime.Date(DateTime.now)
    imei = pID.GetDeviceId

    filename = forDate & imei& "_.jpeg"
    File.MakeDir(File.DirRootExternal,"/data/data/a3a/cam/update/images")
    out = File.OpenOutput(File.DirRootExternal,"/data/data/a3a/cam/update/images/"&filename, False)
    out.WriteBytes(Data, 0, Data.Length)
    out.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Approach without library:

```
Sub UploadImage(Dir As String, Filename As String) As Byte()
    Dim Image As Bitmap = LoadBitmapSample(Dir, Filename, 1920, 1080)
    Dim Out As OutputStream
    Out.InitializeToBytesArray(100)
    Image.WriteToStream(Out, 90, "JPEG")
    Return Out.ToBytesArray
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add RSImageProcessing library to your project.

This code will be bright your mind :)

```
Sub ReSize(b As Bitmap, newWidth As Int, newHeight As Int) As Bitmap
   Dim r As RSImageProcessing
   Return r.scaleBitmap(b, newWidth, newHeight)
End Sub
```